# bootstrap column full height with scrollbar if needed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following (kind of) code :

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              header
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div id="logo-frame" class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" class="img-fluid overflow-auto">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              footer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          side
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The image is of loaded dynamically and can be of any size and aspect ratio.
I want the div #logo-frame to :

- take up all vertical space available (the container has `min-height: 100vh` but I'm not sure how to have the div eat it all up with flexbox) and pad the image with whitespace if required
- have the image inside centered horizontally and vertically (I think I got it covered with `justify-content-center align-items-center`)
- show a scrollbar if the height becomes too big to show the image (e.g with https://via.placeholder.com/1000x2000) but only on the image, not on the full page (I think the `overflow-auto` is enough, but not sure...)

How can I achieve this behavior easily with flexbox ?
Thanks

**UPDATE**

The following code is working.

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid" style="height : 100vh">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-8 h-100">
      <div class="card h-100">
        <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column h-100">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              header
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row h-100 overflow-auto">
              <div id="logo-frame" class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x300" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
              footer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
          side
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me understand :

1. if it is possible to not have to cascade down the `h-100` ?
2. why if I put `min-height:100vh` instead of `height:100vh`, it does not work ?
3. why if I don't put `d-flex flex-column` on the `card-body` element, it does not work
4. if there's a better way to make this work ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the "max-height" css attribute in the parent container in conjunction with an auto scroll on overflow?

**Update per your request**

```
<!-- Add Slimscroll library -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-slimScroll/1.3.8/jquery.slimscroll.js" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**Refactored Markup**

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="min-height: 100vh;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            header
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- as indicated in style attribute: Add a class w/these attribs/values -->
            <div id="logo-frame" style="max-height: 1000px; overflow: hidden;" class="col d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <!-- you might need to remove the css selector: overflow-auto from the class attrib (Test it) -->
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x1200" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
            footer
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        side
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Instantiate Slimscroll on load**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#logo-frame').slimScroll({  
        // According to slimscroll documentation - leave height empty      
        height: '',
        width: '100%',
        alwaysVisible: false
    });
})
```

Comment: How would that help ? what value for max-height should I use ? can you post a working code with a solution ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want to have to add any external dependency I don't think I need. Also, I don't know what value of min-height I should put in advance, it depends on the size of the viewing screen.